# How to save image in a file and save the name of image to database using MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, image

I need to save image that user select from file upload control to a file in the site like Content/Images and use a GUID for name of this image and save this GUID to database.
I'm new in MVC so please help me with details.
Thank you All.
Here is my Controller...

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Product product,HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        if (file!=null&&file.ContentLength>0)
        {
            var FileName = string.Format("{0}.{1}",Guid.NewGuid(),file.ContentType);
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images"), FileName);
            file.SaveAs(path);
        }
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Products.AddObject(product);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.CategoryID = new SelectList(db.Categories, "CategoryID", "CategoryName", product.CategoryID);
        return View(product);
    }
```

And here is my View...

```
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Product", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {
            <input type="file" name="Uploader" />
        }
```

I don't know what happend at all...
but there is no HttpPostedFileBase instance so The if statement is fail.

Comment: It sounds like homework... and it sounds like you didn't even try yourself so far...

Comment: Actually i tried every thing but i can't find the answer.if you now how i can do that please let me know how instead of mocking.tnx 4 your consideration by the way.

Comment: Usually you should show some code that you tried with and explain what error you get or what specific problem you have. Asking for an entire solution is not the way to go on stack overflow. This is way you're not getting any answer

Answer (score 0):

In your view, the `<input type="file" />` should have the name `"file"` so that the Model Binder will assign it to the `file` parameter in your action.

So basically:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Product", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) 
    { 
        <input type="file" name="file" /> 
    }
```

Comment: Your also both missing the second parameter `Product product`. Either assign them default values in your controller. or add a field (hidden or otherwise) on your view.

Comment: I set the Name as above but it still don't work.the if statement fail because HttpPostedFileBase instance is null!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try rename HttpPostedFileBase parameter from file to Uploader and test again

change from public ActionResult Create(Product product,HttpPostedFileBase file)
to public ActionResult Create(Product product,HttpPostedFileBase Uploader)

I mean name of html tag and parameter name are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Change your action to this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Product product)
{
    var files = controllerContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Files;

    foreach (string inputName in files)
    {
        file = files[inputName];

        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var FileName = string.Format("{0}.{1}", Guid.NewGuid(), file.ContentType);
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images"), FileName);
            file.SaveAs(path);
        }

    }

    ... do other stuff here ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need some condition that is like below..
The Contenttype value is like this image/png, image/gif, image/jpeg so when you combine it something like this:

0f269598-0d66-4453-a3b5-a8f07254c531.image/png

Code here

```
string fileExt = "jpg";
if (Imagename.ContentType == "image/png") { fileExt = "png"; }
else if (Imagename.ContentType == "image/gif") { fileExt = "gif"; }
else if (Imagename.ContentType == "image/jpeg") { fileExt = "jpg"; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this instead of comparing all the image types :

```
 fileName = string.Format("{0}{1}", Guid.NewGuid(),
 Path.GetExtension(file.FileName));
```

Answer (score 0):

why dont you add 'HttpPostedFileBase file' in the product model instead of sending it separately eg:
model:

```
 public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
```

view:

```
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.File, new { type = "file" })
```

it worked like a charm for me !!

oh.by the way.if you are using database first entity model..you need to add that extra field through partial class ie.

```
public partial class Product                    
    {
        public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
    }
```